# Share strings.xml between apps in android

Tags: android

I have multiple projects that use the same localized strings.xml. How do I share this file between all my projects so that to edit only one file?

Comment: @Simon Eclipse, default settings

Answer (score 0):

Create an [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) that includes the strings and whatever resources you want to share.